# How do I link to a sheet in my workbook based on cell value?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, formula

I have a column with document chapter references in it - such as:

```
4.2.3.1 
4.2.3.2
4.2.4.4
etc
```

My workbook has sheets with these references as names. Is there a way to automatically hyperlink the chapter references to the correct sheet in my workbook so I click "4.2.3.1" in my chapter column and it opens the correct sheet in my workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way without VBA is to add another column and put a hyperlink formula in it so if the chapter reference is in A1 and the name of your workbook is Book1, put this in B1:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1]"&A1&"!A1")
```

Then click on B1.

Comment: Thanks for that. Much appreciated :-)